# What is the purpose of key in MSGGET

Tags: unix, ipc

Can someone please explain the purpose of key in msgget? The return value of the function is the identifier we use for msgsnd and msgrcv, so why do we add a key?

Moreover, can we define a message queue with our own identifier? let's say I want to create a message queue with a specific identifier, can I make sure msgget returns checks if that identifier exists already,and if it doesnt, to return it?

Comment: key as in the first parameter of msgget

Comment: Did you read the specification here:  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/msgget.html ?  It states that the `key` is used to identify a message queue:  *The `msgget()` function shall return the message queue identifier associated with the argument `key`.*